# Does including a [puppet] profile within another profile break the module-profile-role pattern?

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet and am trying to figure out how to organize modules, profiles, and roles. My general understanding of the module-profile-role pattern is that each server gets one role, roles are built from profiles, and profiles are built from modules. Here is a rough diagram I made to help me visualize this:

[image]

I have a profile in which I want to include another profile (using example above: wordpress-server could include server-core, since I will never deploy wordpress-server without server-core).

Does this break the pattern?

---

*edit:*

To expand on my question based on feedback, here is a hypothetical group of profiles. I will name in a special way so we can see how they inherit from each other: underscores will be used to represent that a profile inherits from another (sub) profile.

`|-profile/manifests/
     |---- base
     |---- base_linux
     |---- base_linux_server
     |---- base_linux_workstation
     |---- base_windows
     |---- base_windows_workstation
     |---- base_windows_server`

Now let's add a profile called "hardened" which is cross-platform and we want it on all servers. This messes up our naming scheme a bit, but we can manage:

`|-profile/manifests/
     |---- base
     |---- base_linux
     |---- base+hardening_linux_server
     |---- base_linux_workstation
     |---- base_windows
     |---- base_windows_workstation
     |---- base+hardening_windows_server
     |---- hardening`

aaand now let's really mess things up and create a profile for a workstation and a server:

`|-profile/manifests/
     |---- base
     |---- base_linux
     |---- base+hardening_linux_server
     |---- base_linux_workstation
     |---- base_windows
     |---- base_windows_workstation
     |---- base+hardening_windows_server
     |---- hardening
     |---- base+hardening_linux_server_+_base_linux`

Okay, so that's a bit of a mess, but my real concern is how this would look to a new recruit if we didn't use this naming scheme:

`|-profile/manifests/
     |---- base
     |---- linux_core
     |---- linux_server
     |---- linux_workstation
     |---- windows
     |---- desktop_pc
     |---- win_server
     |---- hardening
     |---- server_and_workstation`

If the new recruit is tasked to create a new role, there is no way to make sense of this short of looking into every profile. Including profiles within other profiles breaks the assumption that we can look at module/profile/ to see what to include in a role.

So, to re-phrase my initial question a bit:

Is this profile-mess typical and expected, or did this all happen because I broke the module-profile-role pattern?

Comment: Roles and profiles is all opinion-based, so you are only 'breaking it' or 'doing it wrong' if you are increasing the complexity/difficulty of working with your codebase. Also, what is wrong with your current design that you want to change it?

Comment: I am dramatically expanding on my current design and trying to balance between maximum DRY-ness (including another profile within another), and minimal cognitive load (easy-to-understand design pattern).

I am hoping that someone with more experience with puppet will be able to guide my decision, since it is not yet clear to me the full consequences of either choice.

Comment: That's a nice diagram, and it seems to show that you have a good overall grasp of the pattern.  I'm inclined to agree with @MattSchuchard, however, that the kind of detail you're asking about is a matter of opinion -- different people may reasonably interpret the pattern differently.  And really, it's also a question of what you choose to call a "module" (technically, everything, including your role and profile classes, should be in modules), and what you call a profile.  If you don't want to include one profile inside another, then you could consider demoting the former to "module" status.

Answer (score 1):

Profiles are many, roles are singular. So your roles should still be singletons, but it's fine to have profiles within profiles, as you're still keeping your code DRY still.

You say you're concerned that there might be consequences, but I can't think of anything really bad happening, other than it might increase the number of manifests in your control repo.

It's important to remember, the roles and profile pattern is not gospel. It's a framework to make sure that you keep your code DRY and makes it easier for your developers/sysadmins to visualise how parts fit together. Sometimes it's ok to bend or even break the rules if it works for your organisation or team.

For example, I was working with a team that had a really big base profile with all their component modules in it, and it was becoming hard to manage. So I helped refactor it to something like this:

```
class profiles::base {

  # include all base profiles
  include ::profiles::base::issue
  include ::profiles::base::motd
  include ::profiles::base::ntp
  include ::profiles::base::postfix
  include ::profiles::base::resolver
  include ::profiles::base::selinux
  include ::profiles::base::snmpd
  include ::profiles::base::sshd
  include ::profiles::base::sysctl

  # include all hardening profiles
  include ::profiles::base::hardening::auditd
  include ::profiles::base::hardening::firewall
  include ::profiles::base::hardening::limits
  include ::profiles::base::hardening::networking
  include ::profiles::base::hardening::shadow
  include ::profiles::base::hardening::xconfig
}
```

This means you have sub-profiles inside base, otherwise the base profile can get pretty complex pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and example. By "consequences" I'm not so much concerned about things breaking as I am confusing the next person who looks into this codebase. I think including a profile within another makes sense, but so far I have only been trying things out with simple profiles within my mostly-pretend architecture.

Comment: For example, I would find the number of modules in that profile to be greatly increasing the difficulty of codebase maintenance. So, all opinion-based towards what your team wants.

Comment: @PeterSouter : after thinking some more I think your example is a bit different from my question. Imagine instead that you wanted two profiles: the one you have above, and one with no hardening (base profiles only). To do this you might copy-paste the base profiles into a new profile, or you might put them into a "core" profile which you could then include above. But: now you have two profiles at the same level and one is included in the other; I think this could quickly become confusing.